# Cassandra A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: (WINDOWS)

Tags: java, cassandra

I have installed cassandra correctly but when I type `cassandra` in the cmd I get this error.

Cassandra 3.11,
JDK 8 & Python 2.7.18

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=12960, tid=0x0000000000000eac
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_321-b07) (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.321-b07 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Windows\System32\hs_err_pid12960.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Closed due to being a duplicate.  Basically, find and rename the `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll` to prevent that library from loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several known issues with running Cassandra on Windows so support is limited. In fact, Windows support was completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

The recommended workarounds are:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using
  software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster
  with [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier and you can launch a cluster in 5 clicks. Cheers!